# Don't working Linq.xml template

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I need get list of attributes from an XML file which satisfies a condition. Example:

```
<rows>    
    <row code="16" type="M" grv="К">
        <cell column="К" dic="s_okved" format="C(8)" inputType="1" vldType="4"
              vld="pril_okved_11" />
    </row>
    <row code="17" type="M" grv="К">
        <cell column="К" dic="s_okved" format="C(8)" inputType="1" vldType="2"
              vld="pril" />
    </row>
</rows>
```

I want to get value "pril_okved_11". Here is my code:

```
var needFilterDic = template.Root.Elements().Descendants()
                        .Where(e => e.Attribute("vldType").Value.Equals("4"))
                        .Attributes("vld");
```

It feels correct to me, but it is  not working. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you weren't far off.  Try:

```
 XDocument.Parse(xml)
          .Descendants()
          .First(e => e.Attribute("vldType") != null && e.Attribute("vldType").Value == "4")
          .Attribute("vld")
          .Value;
```

Or if you are using C# 6 :

```
 XDocument.Parse(xml)
          .Descendants()
          .First(e => e.Attribute("vldType")?.Value == "4")
          .Attribute("vld")
          .Value;
```

you need to verify that your test attribute `vldType` exists before trying to get the value of it.  If it doesn't exist, move on.

Additionally, you can replace `Where` with `First` here as you want the first result.  Also you can remove the `.Root` and `.Elements`, and go straight to `Descendants`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I missed check for existence. Working

Comment: template.Root.Elements().Descendants().Where(e => e.Attribute("vldType") != null && e.Attribute("vldType").Value == "4").Attributes("vld");

Comment: If this answer solved your problem I'd appreciate you clicking the green check next to it